# Is Swift really slow at dealing with numbers?

Tags: performance, swift, primes

As I was playing around with a swift tutorial, I started to write a custom `isPrime` method to check if a given `Int` is prime or not.

After writing it I realized it was working properly but found it a bit slow to perform `isPrime` on some *quite* large numbers (still much lower then `Int.max`).

So I wrote the same piece of code in objc and the code was executed much faster (a factor of 66x).

Here is the swift code:

```
class Swift {
    class func isPrime(n:Int) -> Bool {
        let sqr : Int = Int(sqrt(Double(n))) + 1
        for i in 2...sqr {
            if n % i == 0 {
                return false
            }
        }
        return true;
    }
    class func primesInRange(start:Int, end:Int) -> Int[] {
        var primes:Int[] = Int[]()
        for n in start...end {
            if self.isPrime(n) {
                primes.append(n)
            }
        }
        return primes;
    }
}
```

And the objc code:

```
@implementation Utils

+ (BOOL)isPrime:(NSUInteger)n {
    NSInteger sqr = (NSUInteger)(sqrt(n))+1;
    for (NSUInteger i = 2; i < sqr; ++i) {
        if (n % i == 0) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return YES;
}

+ (NSArray*)primesInRange:(NSUInteger)start end:(NSUInteger)end {
    NSMutableArray* primes = [NSMutableArray array];
    for (NSUInteger i = start; i <= end; ++i) {
        if ([self isPrime:i])
            [primes addObject:@(i)];
    }

    return primes.copy;
}

@end
```

And in `main.swift`:

```
let startDateSwift = NSDate.date()
let swiftPrimes = Swift.primesInRange(1_040_101_022_000, end: 1_040_101_022_200)
let elapsedSwift = NSDate.date().timeIntervalSinceDate(startDateSwift)*1000

let startDateObjc = NSDate.date()
let objcPrimes = Utils.primesInRange(1_040_101_022_000, end: 1_040_101_022_200)
let elapsedObjc = NSDate.date().timeIntervalSinceDate(startDateObjc)*1000

println("\(swiftPrimes) took: \(elapsedSwift)ms");
println("\(objcPrimes) took: \(elapsedObjc)ms");
```

This produces:

```
[1040101022027, 1040101022039, 1040101022057, 1040101022099, 1040101022153] took: 3953.82004976273ms
[1040101022027, 1040101022039, 1040101022057, 1040101022099, 1040101022153] took: 66.4250254631042ms
```

I know that I could have used an `extension` on `Int` here to check if a number is prime, but I wanted both code to be very similar.

Can anyone tell me why this swift code is so much slower? The 66x factor is pretty scary and only gets worse as I increment the range.

Comment: Did you take a look at the generated assembler code? I think, that would be quite instructive.

Comment: First, reverse the order of the tests and see if the results are the same. I don't see why it would matter in this case, but in other contexts you could definitely get caching effects, etc.

Comment: @cmaster xcode 6 (6A215l) doens't seem to support `Assembly View` for swif yet. @"Tom Zych" yes i tried that too but the same result. objc just out runs swift in any order.

Comment: unoptimized Swift is slow. see here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101718/swift-performance-sorting-arrays

Comment: I think `for i in 2...sqr` should be `for i in 2..sqr`. You include i=sqr in Swift but not Obj-C. ... vs .. such a mistake in swift.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Here are optimization levels for the Swift compiler's code generation (you can find them in Build Settings):

```
[-Onone] no optimizations, the default for debug.
[-O]     perform optimizations, the default for release.
[-Ofast] perform optimizations and disable runtime overflow checks and runtime type checks.
```

Using your code I got these times at different levels of optimization:

**[-Onone]**

```
Swift: 6110.98903417587ms
Objc:  134.006023406982ms
```

**[-O]**

```
Swift: 89.8249745368958ms
Objc:  85.5680108070374ms
```

**[-Ofast]**

```
Swift: 77.1470069885254ms
Objc:  76.3399600982666ms
```

Keep in mind that -Ofast is comes with risks. e.g. It will silently ignore integer and array overflows, producing nonsense results, so if you choose to use it you'll have to guarantee yourself that overflows aren't possible in your program.

Comment: So for the default production level optimization, swift when dealing with numbers is *not* the 2x faster that apple claimed at wwdc!?

Comment: @ryan I'm sure they chose a test case very carefully.

Comment: @ryan it runs faster inside the reality distortion field.

Comment: Don't forget that Swift isn't at v1 yet, it will be a good test to run this code again when Swift is released.

Answer (score 5):

Credits to @sjeohp for his comment which is basically the answer to the question.

I tried optimizing the code to the most aggressive way in `Release` for both LLVM and Swift optimizations:

[image]

[image]

Compiled the project in `Release` and got:

```
[1040101022027, 1040101022039, 1040101022057, 1040101022099, 1040101022153] took: 63.211977481842ms
[1040101022027, 1040101022039, 1040101022057, 1040101022099, 1040101022153] took: 60.0320100784302ms
```

Again, thanks @sjeohp for catching this !