# Terribly Slow migrated Objc to swift code

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

In an application I've written I have a process that parses a large amount of data from Core-Data and displays it to a graph.  While doing this processing I also end up writing the data out to a CSV File.  I created a separate class called *CSVLine* which assists with the creation of the CSV file.
For my test case of 140k recorded my Objective-C code takes aprox 12 seconds to run.  After "migrating" the class over to swift It now takes somewhere between 280-360 seconds to run.  Obviously I've done something terrible.

Using Instruments I was able to identify the "slow" method and I was wondering if I've done something clear in SWIFT to cause the issue.

## Objc

```
- (void)newLine {
//    NSLog(@"Appending %@", self.csvString);

    [outData appendData:[self csvData] ];
    [self clear];
}

- (void)clear {

    // Erase every single value

    for (NSUInteger i = 0; i < [values count]; i ++) {
        values[i] = @"";
    }
}
```

## Swift

```
func newLine() {
    outData.appendData(csvData())
    clear()
}


// Clear out the Array
func clear() {
    for (var i = 0; i < values.count; i++) {
        values[i] = ""
    }
}
```

I'm working with various types of data that are all being written to a single CSV file so there are many blank lines.  To accommodate for this I designed this class so that it has an array of `keys` and an array of `values`.  The `keys` store the "column" names for the CSV file and values will store either a blank or a value for the index of the `key` for that data element.

Example:

Keys = [speed,heading,lat,lon]

values might be [200,300,"",""]

or ["","","38.553","25.2256"]

Once I'm done with a line i will write a comma joined list of the values into an internal data structure and clear out the line (erase all the items in the `values` array).  This seems to be where the slowdown is with the swift class.  **Is there something blatantly "slow" i'm doing when i zero out my array?**

## Full Swift Class

```
@objc class CSVLineSwift : NSObject {
    
    // Define Arrays
    var keys: [String] = [String]()
    var values: [String] = [String]()
    
    var outData : NSMutableData = NSMutableData()
    
    override init() {
        
    }
    
    // Singelton Operator - Thread Safe :: http://code.martinrue.com/posts/the-singleton-pattern-in-swift
    class var instance : CSVLineSwift {
    
        // Computed Property
        struct Static {
            static var instance : CSVLineSwift?
            static var token: dispatch_once_t = 0
            }
    
        dispatch_once(&Static.token) {
            Static.instance = CSVLineSwift();
        }
        
        return Static.instance!
    }
    
    // Erase existing Data
    func newFile() {
        outData = NSMutableData();
        outData.appendData(headerData())
    }
    
    func csvString() -> String {
        return ",".join(values)
    }
    
    func csvData() -> NSData {
        let string = csvString()
        let data = string.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
        return data!
    }
    
    
    func addField(field : String) {
        keys.append(field)
        values.append("")
    }
    
    func setValueForKey(value:String, key:String) {

        if let index = find(keys, key) {
            values[index] = value
        } else {
            print( "ERROR -- There was no key: \(key) in the header Array")
        }
    }
    
    func headerString() -> String {
        return ",".join(keys)
    }
    
    func headerData() -> NSData {
       return headerString().dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)!
    }
    
 
    func newLine() {
        outData.appendData(csvData())
        clear()
    }
    
    
    // Clear out the Array
    func clear() {
        for (var i = 0; i < values.count; i++) {
            values[i] = ""
        }
    }
    
    func writeToFile(fileName : String) {
        outData.writeToFile(fileName, atomically: true)
    }
   
}
```

Comment: Are you sure you're testing with a release build in both cases?  With Swift, the difference in performance between debug and release builds can be vast.

Comment: I think i just discovered that ... cause now its running fine - its the optimization isn't it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It appears my issues were due to a debug build.  In debug build there is no optimization.  Once you do a run build the optimization kicks in and things run MUCH MUCH faster....

Similar to the answer posted here:  [Is Swift really slow at dealing with numbers?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24162475/is-swift-really-slow-at-dealing-with-numbers)

Comment: Zeroing an array with 16,737,732 bytes, in my test case, went from 2.37 seconds (no optimization) to 0.0165 seconds (optimized). THAT'S 143 TIMES FASTER! Btw, took C's `memset` only 0.00827seconds on the same machine -- that' another 2x speedup.

Answer (score 5):

Be sure that Swift's optimization level in Build Settings is not -Onone. In my experience, it is orders of magnitude slower than -O. (-O is also the default for 'release', so alternatively you could simply build for release, as already suggested.) As for 'zeroing out' the array, it might be faster (although I do not know) to simply re-initialize the array with a repeated value:

```
values = [String](count: values.count, repeatedValue: "")
```

Or if you know you will be appending the new values as you go along, and are not bound to using the indices, you could call:

```
values.removeAll(keepCapacity: true)
```

And add the new values with values.append() rather than at indices.

Comment: Thanks!  I'll give both of these a shot.  The build settings was the culprit.