# How to insert values into a nested Swift Dictionary

Tags: dictionary, collections, swift

I'm trying to insert new key-value pair in dictionary, which nested in another one `Dictionary`:

```
var dict = Dictionary<Int, Dictionary<Int, String>>()

dict.updateValue([1 : "one", 2: "two"], forKey: 1)
dict[1]?[1] // {Some "one"}

if var insideDic =  dict[1] {
    // it is a copy, so I can't insert pair this way:
    insideDic[3] = "three"
}

dict // still [1: [1: "one", 2: "two"]]

dict[1]?[3] = "three" // Cannot assign to the result of this expression
dict[1]?.updateValue("three", forKey: 3) // Could not find a member "updateValue"
```

I believe should be a simple way to handle it, but I spent an hour and still can't figure it out. 
I can use `NSDictionary` instead, but I really like to understand how I should manage nested `Dictionaries` in Swift?

Comment: possible duplicate of [swift: modifying arrays inside dictionaries](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24534229/swift-modifying-arrays-inside-dictionaries)

Comment: Yes, it is essentially the same struggle. Sorry, I missed it at first time. Should I somehow link to it and close this one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Dictionarys are value types so are copied on assignment. As a result you are going to have to get the inner dictionary (which will be a copy), add the new key, then re-assign.

```
// get the nested dictionary (which will be a copy)
var inner:Dictionary<Int, String> = dict[1]!

// add the new value
inner[3] = "three"

// update the outer dictionary
dict[1] = inner
println(dict) // [1: [1: one, 2: two, 3: three]]
```

You could use one of the new utility libraries such as [ExSwift](https://github.com/pNre/ExSwift) to make this a bit simpler:

```
dict[1] = dict[1]!.union([3:"three"])
```

This uses the [union method](https://github.com/pNre/ExSwift#instance-methods-5) that combines two dictionaries.

Comment: Uurgh… Swift at its worst. We shouldn't be having to use utility libraries to do this.

Comment: True, the array and dictionary behaviour is causing a *lot* of confusion at the moment.

Comment: Thank you, now it is clear. It takes cognitive shift to accept this answer... feels so counterintuitive. And I only hope compiler will optimize it to dust, because in my real case this dictionary is huge.

Comment: Performance is the issue in current state of Swift, see [Swift's Dictionary is slow even with -Ofast](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24476943/swifts-dictionary-is-slow-even-with-ofast?lq=1)

Comment: @IlyaBelikin you could cheat to make it work - rather than storing dictionaries within dictionaries, Create a class which acts as a dictionary reference, and store this in your 'outer' dictionary instead!

Comment: I don't think this is correct anymore; see e.g. [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41566988/539599).