# How can I extend dictionaries whose values are dictionaries themselves?

Tags: swift, dictionary, generics, swift-extensions

Say I want to extend nested dictionaries with some functionality. Using pseudo-Swift, this is my goal:

```
extension Dictionary where Value: Dictionary {
    typealias K1 = Key
    typealias K2 = Value.Key
    typealias V  = Value.Value

    subscript(k1: K1, k2: K2) -> V? {
        return self[k1]?[k2]
    }
}
```

I can not get this to work, though. Type bounds can not be non-protocol types; no protocol that Dictionary implements provides the methods I and types I need to refer to; getting access to the types of generics is cumbersome; and so on. Nothing I tried works out.

What is a solution for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One trick (dare I say pattern?) we can use here is to define our *own* protocol (which we never intend to use anywhere else) which declares all we need and we know `Dictionary` conforms to, anyway.

```
protocol DictionaryProtocol {
    associatedtype Key: Hashable
    associatedtype Value

    subscript(key: Key) -> Value? { get set }
}

extension Dictionary: DictionaryProtocol {}

extension Dictionary where Value: DictionaryProtocol {
    typealias K1 = Key
    typealias K2 = Value.Key
    typealias V  = Value.Value

    subscript(k1: K1, k2: K2) -> V? {
        return self[k1]?[k2]
    }
}
```

This solution carries over to arrays of arrays, and probably many similar cases.