# Replace [string : string] at specific index Swift

Tags: swift

To replace a string at specific index from

```
var stringArray:[String] = ["value1", "value2", "value3", "value4"]
```

We use

```
stringArray[2] = "new string"
```

**var myNewDictArray = [Dictionary< String, String> ] ()**

In my case i have

```
key/value pair
    ▿ (2 elements)
      - .0: "answer"
      - .1: "0"
  ▿ 1 key/value pair
    ▿ (2 elements)
      - .0: "answer"
      - .1: "0"
  ▿ 1 key/value pair
    ▿ (2 elements)
      - .0: "answer"
      - .1: "0"
  ▿ 1 key/value pair
    ▿ (2 elements)
      - .0: "answer"
      - .1: "0"
  ▿ 1 key/value pair
    ▿ (2 elements)
      - .0: "answer"
      - .1: "0"
  ▿ 1 key/value pair
    ▿ (2 elements)
      - .0: "answer"
      - .1: "0"
```

In my array

**When i try to replace dictionary at specific index say 5,**
It shows up error:

> Swift:: Error: contextual type '[String : String]' cannot be used with
>   array lit eral
>           myNewDictArray[index] = ["answer", "option3"]

Code im using is

```
for (index, element) in myNewDictArray.enumerated() {

    if(index==5) {

        myNewDictArray[index] = ["answer", "option3"]

    } 

}
```

I also tried

```
for (index, element) in myNewDictArray.enumerated() {

    if(index==5) {

        myNewDictArray[index].value(forKey:"answer") = "option3"

    } 

}
```

Then error is

> Swift:: Error: value of type '[String : String]' has no member 'value'
>           myNewDictArray[index].value(forKey:"answer") = "option3"

Comment: You may be interested in [my answer to a similar question](http://stackoverflow.com/a/41570649/539599).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This data structure is not a dictionary. It is an array of dictionaries.

```
myNewDictArray[index] = ["answer", "option3"]
```

The above doesn't work because `["answer", "option3"]` is an array literal. You are assigning an array to a dictionary. So it of course won't work.

You can make it a dictionary literal by replacing the `,` with a `:`:

```
myNewDictArray[index] = ["answer": "option3"]
```

But I suggest you to use an array of tuples to store this data:

```
var myTupleArray = [(String, String)]()
```

Answer (score 3):

You probably looking for `subscript` with your array of dictionary.

```
var myNewDictArray = [[String:String]]()// OR [Dictionary< String, String>]()
//If you want to update specific key value pair
myNewDictArray[index]["answer"] = "option3"
//If you want to replace whole dictionary with new one
myNewDictArray[index] = ["answer" : "option3"]
```