# How to benchmark Swift code execution?

Tags: swift, performance

Is there a way/software to give precise time needed to execute a block of code written in Swift, other than the following?

```
let date_start = NSDate()

// Code to be executed 

println("\(-date_start.timeIntervalSinceNow)")
```

Comment: ... you mean other than using Instruments? You actually want to get this stuff for yourself? You don't just want to know it as a human being, you need your code to be able to work it out?

Answer (score 166, accepted):

If you just want a standalone timing function for a block of code, I use the following Swift helper functions:

```
func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title:String, operation:()->()) {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s.")
}

func timeElapsedInSecondsWhenRunningCode(operation: ()->()) -> Double {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    return Double(timeElapsed)
}
```

The former will log out the time required for a given section of code, with the latter returning that as a float. As an example of the first variant:

```
printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title:"map()") {
    let resultArray1 = randoms.map { pow(sin(CGFloat($0)), 10.0) }
}
```

will log out something like:

> Time elapsed for map(): 0.0617449879646301 s

Be aware that [Swift benchmarks will vary heavily based on the level of optimization you select](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24102237/19679), so this may only be useful for relative comparisons of Swift execution time. Even that may change on a per-beta-version basis.

Comment: An issue with this technique is that it introduces a new scope, so anything declared within that scope won't be available outside it (e.g. in your example resultArray1 won't be available to code subsequent to the closure.

Answer (score 44):

If you want to get insight into performance of a certain block of code and make sure performance doesn't hurt when you make edits, best thing would be using [XCTest's](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest) measuring performance functions, like `measure(_ block: () -> Void)`.

Write a unit test that executes method you want to benchmark, and that unit test will run it multiple times giving you time needed and deviation of results

```
func testExample() {

    self.measure {
        //do something you want to measure
    }
}
```

You can find more info in apple docs under [Testing with Xcode -> Performance Testing](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/DeveloperTools/Conceptual/testing_with_xcode/chapters/03-testing_basics.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014132-CH3-SW7)

Comment: Be aware `measureBlock` will execute the block code multiple times to get better statistics.

Comment: what is `measureBlock`? where does it come from (what should I import)? in Swift 4

Comment: measureBlock() is a method on XCTestCase. import XCTest... File -> new -> test case  template will have that block added to it by default

Answer (score 19):

You can use this function to measure asynchronous as well as synchronous code:

```
import Foundation

func measure(_ title: String, block: (@escaping () -> ()) -> ()) {

    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()

    block {
        let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
        print("\(title):: Time: \(timeElapsed)")
    }
}
```

So basically you pass a block that accepts a function as a parameter, which you use to tell measure when to finish.

For example to measure how long some call called "myAsyncCall" takes, you would call it like this:

```
measure("some title") { finish in
    myAsyncCall {
        finish()
    }
    // ...
}
```

For synchronous code:

```
measure("some title") { finish in
     // code to benchmark
     finish()
     // ...
}
```

This should be similar to measureBlock from XCTest, though I don't know how exactly it's implemented there.

Comment: @escaping is needed

Answer (score 13):

## Benchmarking Function - Swift 4.2

This is an incredibly versatile benchmarking function that allows for the labelling of tests, performing many tests and averaging their execution times, a setup block to be called between tests (i.e. shuffling an array between measuring a sorting algorithm on it), clear printing of benchmarking results, and it also returns the average execution time as a `Double`.

Try the following:

```
@_transparent @discardableResult public func measure(label: String? = nil, tests: Int = 1, printResults output: Bool = true, setup: @escaping () -> Void = { return }, _ block: @escaping () -> Void) -> Double {
    
    guard tests > 0 else { fatalError("Number of tests must be greater than 0") }
    
    var avgExecutionTime : CFAbsoluteTime = 0
    for _ in 1...tests {
        setup()
        let start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        block()
        let end = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        avgExecutionTime += end - start
    }
    
    avgExecutionTime /= CFAbsoluteTime(tests)
    
    if output {
        let avgTimeStr = "\(avgExecutionTime)".replacingOccurrences(of: "e|E", with: " × 10^", options: .regularExpression, range: nil)
        
        if let label = label {
            print(label, "▿")
            print("\tExecution time: \(avgTimeStr)s")
            print("\tNumber of tests: \(tests)\n")
        } else {
            print("Execution time: \(avgTimeStr)s")
            print("Number of tests: \(tests)\n")
        }
    }
    
    return avgExecutionTime
}
```

---

#### Usage

```
var arr = Array(1...1000).shuffled()

measure(label: "Map to String") {
    let _ = arr.map { String($0) }
}

measure(label: "Apple's Sorting Method", tests: 1000, setup: { arr.shuffle() }) {
    arr.sort()
}

measure {
    let _ = Int.random(in: 1...10000)
}

let mathExecutionTime = measure(printResults: false) {
    let _ = 219 * 354
}

print("Math Execution Time: \(mathExecutionTime * 1000)ms")


// Prints:
//
// Map to String ▿
//     Execution time: 0.021643996238708496s
//     Number of tests: 1
//
// Apple's Sorting Method ▿
//     Execution time: 0.0010601345300674438s
//     Number of tests: 1000
//
// Execution time: 6.198883056640625 × 10^-05s
// Number of tests: 1
//
// Math Execution Time: 0.016927719116210938ms
//
```

**Note:** `measure` also returns the execution time. The `label`, `tests`, and `setup` arguments are optional. The `printResults` argument is set to `true` by default.

Answer (score 3):

I like Brad Larson's answer for a simple test that you can even run in a Playground. For my own needs I've tweaked it a bit:

1. I've wrapped the call to the function I want to test in a testing function, which gives me space to play around with different arguments if I want to.
2. The testing function returns its name, so I don't have to include the 'title' parameter in the `averageTimeTo()` benchmarking function.
3. The benchmarking function allows you to optionally specify how many repetitions to perform (with a default of 10). It then reports both the total and average times.
4. The benchmarking function prints to the console AND returns the `averageTime` (which you might expect from a function called 'averageTimeTo'), so there's no need for two separate functions that have almost identical functionality.

For example:

```
func myFunction(args: Int...) {
    // Do something
}

func testMyFunction() -> String {
    // Wrap the call to myFunction here, and optionally test with different arguments
    myFunction(args: 1, 2, 3)
    return #function
}

// Measure average time to complete test
func averageTimeTo(_ testFunction: () -> String, repeated reps: UInt = 10) -> Double {
    let functionName = testFunction()
    var totalTime = 0.0
    for _ in 0..<reps {
        let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
        testFunction()
        let elapsedTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
        totalTime += elapsedTime
    }
    let averageTime = totalTime / Double(reps)
    print("Total time to \(functionName) \(reps) times: \(totalTime) seconds")
    print("Average time to \(functionName): \(averageTime) seconds\n")
    return averageTime
}

averageTimeTo(testMyFunction)

// Total time to testMyFunction() 10 times: 0.000253915786743164 seconds
// Average time to testMyFunction(): 2.53915786743164e-05 seconds

averageTimeTo(testMyFunction, repeated: 1000)

// Total time to testMyFunction() 1000 times: 0.027538537979126 seconds
// Average time to testMyFunction(): 2.7538537979126e-05 seconds
```

Comment: That's pretty clever! And thank you for sharing. `@discardableResult` could be useful since you are already printing the `averageTime`

Comment: Yeah good point, that would be Swiftier if you're not in the habit of using the return value (as shown in my example!) I didn't even notice, since it doesn't generate a warning in playgrounds.

Answer (score 3):

**Benchmark Swift code execution**

Please make your benchmark on `Production` build instead of `Debug` since it contains more optimizations

you have several possibilities

- `DispatchTime.now().uptimeNanoseconds` (and div on 1_000_000)

  Based on the Mach absolute time unit

Wall Clock(is **not recommended** because of leap second or other micro correction)

- `Date().timeIntervalSince1970`
- `CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent`

Test

- XCTest

```
let metrics: [XCTMetric] = [XCTMemoryMetric(), XCTStorageMetric(), XCTClockMetric()]

let measureOptions = XCTMeasureOptions.default
measureOptions.iterationCount = 3

measure(metrics: metrics, options: measureOptions) {
    //block of code
}
```

*I would not suggest  you to create a general function with `measure` block because Xcode sometimes can not handle it properly. That is why use `measure` block for every performance test

Answer (score 3):

Small improvement of @[Brad Larsons](https://stackoverflow.com/users/19679/brad-larson)'s answer (the accepted answer) to allow the function to return the operation's result if needed

```
@discardableResult func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode<T>(title: String, operation: () -> T) -> T {
    let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    let result = operation()
    let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
    print("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s.")
    
    return result
}
```

Answer (score 1):

```
class TimeMeasurement {
static var shared: TimeMeasurement = TimeMeasurement()
private var start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
func begin() {
    start = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
}
@discardableResult func end() -> Double {
    let diff = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
    print("Took \(diff) seconds")
    return diff
}
```

}

Answer (score 1):

A made a tiny spm package to measure code execution time:

https://github.com/mezhevikin/Measure.git

Example of use

```
Measure.start("create-user")
let user = User()
Measure.finish("create-user")
```

Console output:

```
⏲ Measure [create-user]: 0.00521 sec.
```

Measure async request

```
Measure.start("request")
let url = URL(string: "https://httpbin.org/get")!
URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { _, _, _ in
    let time = Measure.finish("request")
    Analytics.send(event: "Request", ["time" => time])
}.resume()
```

Full code of package:

```
// Mezhevikin Alexey: https://github.com/mezhevikin/Measure
import Foundation

public class Measure {
    static private var starts = [String: Double]()
    
    static public func start(_ key: String) {
        starts[key] = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
    }

    @discardableResult
    static public func finish(_ key: String) -> Double {
        guard let start = starts[key] else {
            print(" Key [\(key)] not found")
            return 0
        }
        let time = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - start
        print(String(format: "⏲ Measure [\(key)]: %.5f sec.", time))
        starts.removeValue(forKey: key)
        return time
    }
}
```