# How to convert Data of Int16 audio samples to array of float audio samples

Tags: swift, audio, nsarray, avfoundation, nsdata

I'm currently working with audio samples.
I get them from AVAssetReader and have a `CMSampleBuffer` with something like this:

```
guard let sampleBuffer = readerOutput.copyNextSampleBuffer() else {
guard reader.status == .completed else { return nil }
// Completed
// samples is an array of Int16
let samples = sampleData.withUnsafeBytes {
  Array(UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>(
  start: $0, count: sampleData.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size))
 }

 // The only way I found to convert [Int16] -> [Float]...
 return samples.map { Float($0) / Float(Int16.max)}
}

guard let blockBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetDataBuffer(sampleBuffer) else {
return nil
}

let length = CMBlockBufferGetDataLength(blockBuffer)
let sampleBytes = UnsafeMutablePointer<UInt8>.allocate(capacity: length)
      CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes(blockBuffer, 0, length, sampleBytes)

      sampleData.append(sampleBytes, count: length)
}
```

As you can see the only I found to convert [Int16] -> [Float] is`samples.map { Float($0) / Float(Int16.max)` but by doing this my processing time is increasing. Does it exist an other way to cast a pointer of Int16 to a pointer of Float?

Comment: If your intention is to convert the integers -32767 ... 32767 to -1.0 ... 1.0 then that's how it is done. But you don't need to create an Array, you can map the UnsafeBufferPointer.

Comment: How would you *"cast a pointer"*? 1) Int16 is 2 bytes and Float is 4 bytes. 2) You *compute* floating point values from the integers.

Comment: @MartinR In fact I would like the iteration to compute a floating point by doing `Int16value / Int16.max`. Isn't a way in Swift to say "Here is a pointer of Int16 could you give me the computed float pointer" ?
When I used a UnsafeMutableRawPointer (a pointer of UInt8) I was able to do something like:
`var floatValues = bytes.bindMemory(to: Float.self, capacity: bytesTotal)`

Comment: Casting (or "rebinding" in Swift lingo) only changes the way how the memory is interpreted, it does not change the memory itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

"Casting" or "rebinding" a pointer only changes the way how memory is
interpreted. You want to *compute* floating point values from integers,
the new values have a different memory representation (and also a different
size).

Therefore you somehow *have to* iterate over all input values
and compute the new values. What you can do is to omit the `Array` 
creation:

```
let samples = sampleData.withUnsafeBytes {
    UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>(start: $0, count: sampleData.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)
}
return samples.map { Float($0) / Float(Int16.max) }
```

Another option would be to use the *vDSP* functions from the
Accelerate framework:

```
import Accelerate
// ...

let numSamples = sampleData.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size
var factor = Float(Int16.max)
var floats: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: numSamples)

// Int16 array to Float array:
sampleData.withUnsafeBytes {
    vDSP_vflt16($0, 1, &floats, 1, vDSP_Length(numSamples))
}
// Scaling:
vDSP_vsdiv(&floats, 1, &factor, &floats, 1, vDSP_Length(numSamples))
```

I don't know if that is faster, you'll have to check.
(*Update:* It is faster, as ColGraff demonstrated in his answer.)

An explicit loop is also much faster than using `map`:

```
let factor = Float(Int16.max)
let samples = sampleData.withUnsafeBytes {
    UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>(start: $0, count: sampleData.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)
}
var floats: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: samples.count)
for i in 0..<samples.count {
    floats[i] = Float(samples[i]) / factor
}
return floats
```

---

An additional option in your case might be to use `CMBlockBufferGetDataPointer()` instead of `CMBlockBufferCopyDataBytes()`
into allocated memory.

Comment: Having some trouble with your first block of code, it's having trouble converting the `UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>.init` `start` parameter from `UnsafeRawBufferPointer` to `UnsafePointer<_>?`

Comment: @ColGraff: My `sampleData` has the type `Data`. I *guessed* that from `sampleData.withUnsafeBytes()` in the question.

Comment: Gotcha, that makes sense.

Answer (score 2):

You can do considerably better if you use the [Accelerate Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/1450096-vdsp_vflt16) for the conversion:

```
import Accelerate

// Set up random [Int]
var randomInt = [Int16]()

randomInt.reserveCapacity(10000)
for _ in 0..<randomInt.capacity {
  let value = Int16(Int32(arc4random_uniform(UInt32(UInt16.max))) - Int32(UInt16.max / 2))
  randomInt.append(value)
}

// Time elapsed helper: https://stackoverflow.com/a/25022722/887210
func printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title:String, operation:()->()) {
  let startTime = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent()
  operation()
  let timeElapsed = CFAbsoluteTimeGetCurrent() - startTime
  print("Time elapsed for \(title): \(timeElapsed) s.")
}

// Testing

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title: "vDSP") {
  var randomFloat = [Float](repeating: 0, count: randomInt.capacity)
  vDSP_vflt16(randomInt, 1, &randomFloat, 1, vDSP_Length(randomInt.capacity))
}

printTimeElapsedWhenRunningCode(title: "map") {
  randomInt.map { Float($0) }
}

// Results
//
// Time elapsed for vDSP   : 0.000429034233093262 s.
// Time elapsed for flatMap: 0.00233501195907593 s.
```

It's an improvement of about 5 times faster.

(Edit: Added some changes suggested by Martin R)

Comment: Seems we had the same idea :) – Some remarks: Your code crashes because randomFloat is created *before* randomInt.capacity is set, that makes it an empty array.  You can simply pass `&randomFloat` to vDSP_vflt16(). The vDSP measurement should include the randomFloat array creation. There is no reason to use flatMap, just `randomInt.map { Float($0) }`

Comment: @MartinR Ahh yeah, I had moved the initialization of `randomFloat` to earlier to neaten up the code and neglected to test for that. I'll correct it and re-test. Thanks!

Comment: Interestingly, `for i in 0..<randomInt.count { randomFloat[i] = Float(randomInt[i]) }` is as fast as the vDSP method.

Comment: @MartinR It's closer. I'm still seeing some improvement, maybe 50% to 75% time when using vDSP vs for loop.

Comment: A bit more discussion of vDSP, caching, and the effects on testing in this chat: https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/152775/swift-vdsp

Answer (score 2):

@MartinR and @ColGraff gave really good answers, and thank you for everybody and the fast replies. 
however I found an easier way to do that without any computation. `AVAssetReaderAudioMixOutput` requires an audio settings dictionary. Inside we can set the key `AVLinearPCMIsFloatKey: true`. This way I will read my data like this

```
let samples = sampleData.withUnsafeBytes {
    UnsafeBufferPointer<Float>(start: $0, 
                               count: sampleData.count / MemoryLayout<Float>.size)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

for: **Xcode 8.3.3 • Swift 3.1**

```
extension Collection where Iterator.Element == Int16 {
    var floatArray: [Float] {
        return flatMap{ Float($0) }
    }
}
```

usage:

```
let int16Array: [Int16] = [1, 2, 3 ,4]    
let floatArray = int16Array.floatArray
```

Comment: Sorry maybe I ddin't explain well but I wanted to convert Int16 audio samples to float audio samples without re iterating the whole samples as you do in the floatArray method.