# Interperating AudioBuffer.mData to display audio visualization

Tags: ios, avfoundation, swift4, core-audio

I am trying to process audio data in real-time so that I can display an on-screen spectrum analyzer/visualization based on sound input from the microphone. I am using AVFoundation's `AVCaptureAudioDataOutputSampleBufferDelegate` to capture the audio data, which is triggering the delgate function `captureOutput`. Function below:

```
func captureOutput(_ output: AVCaptureOutput, didOutput sampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer, from connection: AVCaptureConnection) {

    autoreleasepool {

        guard captureOutput != nil,
            sampleBuffer != nil,
            connection != nil,
            CMSampleBufferDataIsReady(sampleBuffer) else { return }

        //Check this is AUDIO (and not VIDEO) being received
        if (connection.audioChannels.count > 0)
        {
            //Determine number of frames in buffer
            var numFrames = CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBuffer)

            //Get AudioBufferList
            var audioBufferList = AudioBufferList(mNumberBuffers: 1, mBuffers: AudioBuffer(mNumberChannels: 0, mDataByteSize: 0, mData: nil))
            var blockBuffer: CMBlockBuffer?
          CMSampleBufferGetAudioBufferListWithRetainedBlockBuffer(sampleBuffer, nil, &audioBufferList, MemoryLayout<AudioBufferList>.size, nil, nil, UInt32(kCMSampleBufferFlag_AudioBufferList_Assure16ByteAlignment), &blockBuffer)

            let audioBuffers = UnsafeBufferPointer<AudioBuffer>(start: &audioBufferList.mBuffers, count: Int(audioBufferList.mNumberBuffers))

            for audioBuffer in audioBuffers {
                let data = Data(bytes: audioBuffer.mData!, count: Int(audioBuffer.mDataByteSize))

                let i16array = data.withUnsafeBytes {
                    UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>(start: $0, count: data.count/2).map(Int16.init(bigEndian:))
                }

                for dataItem in i16array
                {
                    print(dataItem)
                }

            }

        }
    }
}
```

The code above prints positive and negative numbers of type `Int16` as expected, but need help in converting these raw numbers into meaningful data such as power and decibels for my visualizer.

Comment: **Hint:** You'll need to know about Fast-Fourier Transforms.

Comment: @RobertHarvey - Agreed. But is there an alternative?

Comment: Not if you want to display a spectrum analyzer.  That's how the math works.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Looking into FFT now. Thanks

Comment: @RobertHarvey Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. FFT was necessery, but I wasn't even ready for that yet. These functions need Float arrays. I needed to go back to the basics of bits n' bytes to understand what the Data object even was and understanding how to read Data into arrays before I could even use the FFT functions. Also FFT is really complex. Instead of working with it directly, I found a really good helper Class online that interacts with the Accelerate framework instead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was on the right track... Thanks to *RobertHarvey*'s comment on my question - Use of the Accelerate Framework's FFT calculation functions is required to achieve a spectrum analyzer. But even before I could use these functions, you need to convert your raw data into an `Array` of type `Float` as many of the functions require a `Float` array.

Firstly, we load the raw data into a `Data` object:

```
//Read data from AudioBuffer into a variable
let data = Data(bytes: audioBuffer.mData!, count: Int(audioBuffer.mDataByteSize))
```

I like to think of a `Data` object as a "list" of 1-byte sized chunks of info (8 bits each), but if I check the number of frames I have in my sample and the total size of my `Data` object in bytes, they don't match:

```
//Get number of frames in sample and total size of Data
var numFrames = CMSampleBufferGetNumSamples(sampleBuffer) //= 1024 frames in my case
var dataSize = audioBuffer.mDataByteSize //= 2048 bytes in my case
```

The total size (in bytes) of my data is twice the number of frames I have in my `CMSampleBuffer`. This means that each frame of audio is 2 bytes in length. In order to read the data meaningfully, I need to convert my `Data` object which is a "list" of 1-byte chunks into an array of 2-byte chunks. `Int16` contains 16 bits (or 2 bytes - exactly what we need), so lets create an `Array` of `Int16`:

```
//Convert to Int16 array
let samples = data.withUnsafeBytes {
    UnsafeBufferPointer<Int16>(start: $0, count: data.count / MemoryLayout<Int16>.size)
}
```

Now that we have an `Array` of `Int16`, we can convert it to an `Array` of `Float`:

```
//Convert to Float Array
let factor = Float(Int16.max)
var floats: [Float] = Array(repeating: 0.0, count: samples.count)
for i in 0..<samples.count {
    floats[i] = Float(samples[i]) / factor
}
```

Now that we have our `Float` array, we can now use the Accelerate Framework's complex math to convert the raw `Float` values into meaningful ones like magnitude, decibels etc. Link to documentation:

[Apple's Accelerate Framework](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate)

[Fast Fourier Transform (FFT)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/accelerate/vdsp/fast_fourier_transforms)

I found Apple's documentation rather overwhelming. Luckily, I found a really good example online which I was able to re-purpose for my needs, called [TempiFFT](https://github.com/jscalo/tempi-fft). Implementation as follows:

```
//Initiate FFT
let fft = TempiFFT(withSize: numFrames, sampleRate: 44100.0)
fft.windowType = TempiFFTWindowType.hanning

//Pass array of Floats
fft.fftForward(floats)

//I only want to display 20 bands on my analyzer
fft.calculateLinearBands(minFrequency: 0, maxFrequency: fft.nyquistFrequency, numberOfBands: 20)

//Then use a loop to iterate through the bands in your spectrum analyzer
var magnitudeArr = [Float](repeating: Float(0), count: 20)
var magnitudeDBArr = [Float](repeating: Float(0), count: 20)
for i in 0..<20
{
    var magnitudeArr[i] = fft.magnitudeAtBand(i)
    var magnitudeDB = TempiFFT.toDB(fft.magnitudeAtBand(i))
    //..I didn't, but you could perform drawing functions here...
}
```

Other useful references:

[Converting Data into Array of Int16](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45149413/converting-swift-data-into-int16)

[Converting Array of Int16 to Array of Float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45863240/how-to-convert-data-of-int16-audio-samples-to-array-of-float-audio-samples?noredirect=1&lq=1)