# Which is best tool to use for performance testing of iOS mobile application

Tags: ios, xcode, performance

I have done my development for iOS application, want to figure out the performance of my application at mobile end.

Is there a tool that I can measure the performance of app for front end along with services APIs.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode comes with `Instruments.app`. You can profile all kinds of things in there, both on the simulator and on a real device. Find it in Xcode under Product > Profile.

Answer (score 1):

Check Instruments.app.

If you want to measure response time i think is not revelant because its depends of connectivity, but you can checkout firebase tools i actually using https://firebase.google.com/docs/perf-mon/

I suggest to put some timers in some portions of your code like this:
[How to benchmark Swift code execution?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006235/how-to-benchmark-swift-code-execution)