# Find how long it takes a function to execute in seconds

Tags: ios, swift, date, time

I'm trying to find a way to tell how long its taken a function to execute in seconds. Currently I'm doing it this way:

```
 let startDate = Date()
    let endDate = Date()
    let calendar = Calendar.current
    let dateComponents = calendar.compare(startDate, to: endDate, toGranularity: .second)
    let seconds = dateComponents.rawValue
    print("Seconds: \(seconds)")
```

but every time I print out the seconds it always reads -1.  I've looked into this question: [elapsed time](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2129794/how-to-log-a-methods-execution-time-exactly-in-milliseconds) but I need the output to be in seconds.  Any suggestions?

Comment: Are you looking for this? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006235/how-to-benchmark-swift-code-execution

Comment: `compare` doesn't give you the difference between two times, it just tell someone you whether one is earlier/later than the other down to the given unit https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/calendar/2293166-compare. The question you linked to has the answer you need; a `TimeInterval` is in seconds. just round the value to the nearest whole second if you don't want the fraction

Comment: There are multiple ways to do this. Many users have posted timer methods, etc., however another option if you're using `URLSession` is this: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/urlsessiontaskmetrics#

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```swift
let start = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate

// do stuff

let end = Date.timeIntervalSinceReferenceDate
let secondsElapsed = end - start
```

`secondsElapsed` will be a `Double`, but it will be in seconds. You can round it or truncate it if you want an `Int`.

Hope this helps!