# Measuring execution time with Date()

Tags: swift, performance, date

I want to compare to different implementation of a function:

```
let start1 = Date()
_ = funcImplA()   
let end1 = Date()

let start2 = Date()
_ = funcImplB()
let end2 = Date()

let time1 = end1.timeIntervalSince(start1)
let time2 = end2.timeIntervalSince(start2)
print("ImplA = \(time1 ), ImplB = \(time2)")
```

The results I'm getting is that the first measure is always slower than the second one (`time1 > time2`). Meaning that if I'm switching between the calls, fist measure `funcImplB()` and then `funcImplA`, I'm still get that `time1 > time2`.
What might be the reason?

Comment: Are you testing this in a real, compiled build with optimisations turned on? Swift playgrounds are not suitable for measuring execution time, since they're not actually compiling the code and the real-time displaying of values also significantly affects execution time.

Comment: You can find some examples in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25006235/how-to-benchmark-swift-code-execution/25006361#25006361) of measuring performance

Answer (score 2):

You could test this in unit tests and use [measure block](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/xctest/xctestcase/1496290-measureblock?language=swift)

Please also consider running this on real device, not simulator