# how to get result from last called in locationManager didUpdateToLocation function

Tags: swift

I was doing gps location by using CLLocation. When i press submit button and start the process to get the coordinate. However the locationManager being called multiple times.

How can I get the value from last called in locationManager function ?

Thanks

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift performance: sorting arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101718/swift-performance-sorting-arrays)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`locationManager.location` will give you the most recently retrieved location if it exists, otherwise the value will be nil.