# Swift on Linux: how to specify compiler optimizations

Tags: linux, swift, macos, compilation

Several threads on stackoverflow (e.g. [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101718/swift-performance-sorting-arrays)) discuss the different optimization levels (`Onone`, `O`, `Ounchecked`...) when compiling Swift applications.

However, those postings are related to the development on OSX. It seems that those optimizations can be set directly via Xcode or xcrun (`xcrun swift -O3`).

I'm wondering how to switch the different optimization levels when using the Swift compiler directly on Linux (Ubuntu 15.10). Currently, I'm building the application just by invoking `swift build` as it is shown in the docs, but I found no way no change the optimization level.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to build optimized version of Swift Package using the Swift Package Manager \`swift build\` command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39775937/how-to-build-optimized-version-of-swift-package-using-the-swift-package-manager)

Comment: @MikeC. how is this question a duplicatie if I asked it 9 months earlier than the one provided by you?

Comment: Both questions ask how to specify the swift compiler optimization level and even though the linked question is asked more recently it has a more accurate ("better") selected answer for the current version of the swift package maker (not a workaround). In other words, the other question/answer better serves the community (IMHO).

Comment: @MikeC. Okay, thanks for explaining.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to provide the `-O`, `-Onone`, and `-Ounchecked` optimization flags to the Swift compiler, `swiftc`.  However, it appears that there is currently no way to specify additional flags to `swift build`.  See, for example, the following link, even though it is not directly related:
https://bugs.swift.org/browse/SR-397.  The same bug report suggests that the team is actively working on adding this missing functionality.

One way that I found to work around the problem is to run `swift build -v`, find the first command that references `-Onone`, copy it and all the commands that follow it to a shell script, edit the script to use the desired optimization level instead of `-Onone`, and run the script.  This should re-compile the Swift sources using the desired optimization level and rebuild the executable.

In my testing I found that a simple example involving sorting an array runs a couple of orders of magnitude faster if built using `-O` or `-Ounchecked` instead of `-Onone`.

Comment: Thanks, that's a good workaround. In my tests, `-Ounchecked` was around 4% faster than `-O` in a quicksort implementation and around 19% faster in a genetic algorithm for solving TSPs. Compared to some older results on stack overflow, I think that `-O` got some nice improvements in the meantime.