# How to build optimized version of Swift Package using the Swift Package Manager `swift build` command

Tags: swift, optimization, swift-package-manager

I want to compile my swift code written in the new Swift Package Manager format into highly optimized binary code. This is possible currently using `swiftc -O somefile.swift` But since the swift packages are built using `swift build` command, I cannot pass `-O` option as it does not accept it. So is there a way to specify to optimize the code during the compile process?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can build in a release configuration with: `swift build --configuration release`.

You can also see the tool usage via:

```
$ swift build --help
OVERVIEW: Build sources into binary products

USAGE: swift build [mode] [options]

MODES:
  -c, --configuration <value>   Build with configuration (debug|release) [default: debug]
  --clean [<mode>]              Delete artifacts (build|dist) [default: build]

OPTIONS:
      -C, --chdir <path>       Change working directory before any other operation
  --build-path <path>      Specify build/cache directory [default: ./.build]
  --color <mode>           Specify color mode (auto|always|never) [default: auto]
  -v, --verbose            Increase verbosity of informational output
  -Xcc <flag>              Pass flag through to all C compiler invocations
  -Xlinker <flag>          Pass flag through to all linker invocations
  -Xswiftc <flag>          Pass flag through to all Swift compiler invocations

NOTE: Use `swift package` to perform other functions on packages
```

which lists this option.

See the package manager [reference](https://github.com/apple/swift-package-manager/blob/main/Documentation/Usage.md#setting-the-build-configuration) for more information.

Comment: Thanks for the info. Was able to pass the optimization option by running the following command `swift build -Xswiftc -O`

Comment: Do you happen to know how to get packages that are loaded into XCODE to use this -O flag ? Whenever I use packages they always build unOptimized. Even if the mother project is set to be optimized

Comment: Found a solution. Thanks anyways ✌️

Comment: The link for 'reference' is dead