# How to get an UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Character> from array of Character

Tags: swift, swift3, unsafemutablepointer

I am trying to get an UnsafeMutableBufferPointer using the following code it works sometimes in Playground and it fails also

```
let array : [Character] = ....
func getUnsafeMP(array: [Character]) -> UnsafeMutableBufferPointer<Character> {

    let count = array.count
    let memory = UnsafeMutablePointer<Character>(allocatingCapacity: count)

    for (index , value) in array.enumerated() {

        memory[index] = value //it fails here EXC_BAD_ACCESS
    }

    let buffer = UnsafeMutableBufferPointer(start: memory, count: count)

    return buffer
}
```

Comment: "I am trying to get UnsafeMutableBufferPointer" Can you explain why? It might help to know what you are _really_ trying to accomplish.

Comment: @matt I am playing with swift I want to compare looping using `UnsafeMutableBufferPointer` and the simple `for in enumeration`

Comment: @matt do you have any idea how to achieve that ?

Comment: But what do you want to compare? An array is _not_ an unsafe mutable buffer pointer, so you would be comparing apples and oranges.

Comment: On the matter of speed in accessing array elements, you might want to see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/36160922/341994

Comment: @matt very interesting

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Memory addressed by `UnsafeMutablePointer` can be in one of
three states:

```
/// - Memory is not allocated (for example, pointer is null, or memory has
///   been deallocated previously).
///
/// - Memory is allocated, but value has not been initialized.
///
/// - Memory is allocated and value is initialised.
```

The call

```
let memory = UnsafeMutablePointer<Character>(allocatingCapacity: count)
```

allocates memory, but does not *initialize* it:

```
/// Allocate and point at uninitialized aligned memory for `count`
/// instances of `Pointee`.
///
/// - Postcondition: The pointee is allocated, but not initialized.
public init(allocatingCapacity count: Int)
```

On the other hand, the subscripting methods require that the pointee is initialized:

```
/// Access the pointee at `self + i`.
///
/// - Precondition: the pointee at `self + i` is initialized.
public subscript(i: Int) -> Pointee { get nonmutating set }
```

As a consequence, your code crashes inside `_swift_release_`.

To initialize the allocated memory from the (character) array,
you can use

```
memory.initializeFrom(array)
```

Of course you must de-initialize and deallocate the memory eventually.

---

A different approach is

```
var cArray: [Character] = ["A", "B", "C"]
cArray.withUnsafeMutableBufferPointer { bufPtr  in
    // ...
}
```

Here no new memory is allocated, but the closure is called with
a pointer to the arrays contiguous storage. This buffer pointer
is only valid inside the closure.

Comment: Yup, and it crashes while doing a release because when replacing the value with a subscript, ARC will try to deallocate the previous reference type instance that was contained at that location. His code would have worked using a struct (with no ref inside) or other value types.

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely that you are looking for Array's `withUnsafeBufferPointer` method. This gives you direct access to the array's contiguous in-memory storage. You might want to start with something like this:

```
    let arr = Array("hello there".characters)
    arr.withUnsafeBufferPointer { p -> Void in
        var i = 0
        repeat {
            print("character:", p[i])
            i += 1
        } while i < p.count
    }
```

Comment: Note that this will crash for an empty array as the `repeat` will be evaluated before the `while` – you could just use a for loop instead.

Comment: @originaluser2 Agreed, I just wanted to give something to get started with, as I said. I don't actually have any notion what, if anything, the OP wants to accomplish.