# How do I sort an array of objects in reverse order efficiently?

Tags: swift, algorithm

Suppose I have an array of dictionaries:

```
[ { "id": 2 }, { "id": 59 }, { "id": 31 } ... ]
```

How can I sort this so that it's in descending order, sorted by "id"?

My initial approach is something like:

```
Loop through each element, find the biggest one, and put it into a new array. Then, remove that from the element. Repeat.
```

But I know that's wrong and not efficient.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Swift how to sort array of custom objects by property value](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24130026/swift-how-to-sort-array-of-custom-objects-by-property-value)

Comment: There's a ton of sort related information [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101718/swift-performance-sorting-arrays)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use the sort function in Swift. Something like this:

```
let arr = [["id": 2], ["id": 59], ["id": 31]]
let sortedArr = arr.sort { Int($0["id"]!) > Int($1["id"]!) }
```

Comment: Thanks Rage.  What if It's not [String: Int], but instead it's a custom object (In my case, a message), and it has a property of "id" ?

Comment: just use $0.propertyName instead of $0["id"]. It should work fine.

Comment: check the link provided by Thilo. the gave the same link in comments for your question for custom object sorting.

Comment: `arr.sort{$0.0["id"] > $0.1["id"] }`

Comment: if it was a simple array, you can use the built it sort func: `arr.sort(by: >)` https://apple.co/2FqkBLl

Answer (score 1):

You have only need to use below code that will give you the sorted array using the `sort` because  `dictionary` is also a collection class.

```
let sortedDict = wordDict.sort { $0.0 < $1.0 }
print("\(sortedDict)") //
```

In above code you found the sorted Dictionary. For sorting Array you need to add below code.

```
let sortedArr = arr.sort { Int($0["id"]!) > Int($1["id"]!) }
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if it is the fastest or the better,but swift provides the `sort` method that takes a clojure as an argument. You can write something like that:

```
var ordered = arrdict.sort { (dic1, dic2) -> Bool in
    dic1["id"] > dic2["id"]
}
```

Or compact:

```
var ordered = arrdict.sort { $0["id"] > $1["id"] }
```

The $0..x makes possible to access clojure arguments.
About `sort` algorithm Apple write:

> Discussion The sorting algorithm is not stable (can change the
>   relative order of elements that compare equal).
>
> Requires: The less-than operator (func <) defined in the Comparable
>   conformance is a strict weak ordering over the elements in self.

Answer (score 0):

```
    var val = [ { "id": 2 }, { "id": 59 }, { "id": 31 }];
var a = new Array();


for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
    document.write(Object.keys(val[i]).map(function (key) {return val[i][key]})+"<br>");
    a.push(Object.keys(val[i]).map(function (key) {return val[i][key]}));
}
a.sort();

var result = new Array();
for (i = 0; i < val.length; i++) { 
result.push({"id": a[i]});
}
```