# In swift, is there a way to only check part of an array in a for loop (with a set beginning and ending point)

Tags: swift

So lets say we have an array `a = [20,50,100,200,500,1000]`

Generally speaking we could do `for number in a { print(a) }` if we wanted to check the entirety of a.

How can you limit what indexes are checked? As in have a set beginning and end index (b, and e respectively), and limit the values of number that are checked to between b and e?

For an example, in a, if b is set to 1, and e is set to 4, then only a[1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101718/swift-beta-performance-sorting-arrays) through a[4] are checked.

I tried doing `for number in a[b...e] { print(number) }`, I also saw [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24101718/swift-beta-performance-sorting-arrays) someone do this,
`for j in 0..<n { x[i] = x[j]}`, which works if we want just a ending.

This makes me think I can do something like `for number in b..<=e { print(a[number]) }`
Is this correct?

I'm practicing data structures in Swift and this is one of the things I've been struggling with. Would really appreciate an explanation!

Comment: You seem to have got it already. `for number in a[b...e] { print(number) }` should work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `b..<=e` is not the correct syntax. You need to use **Closed Range Operator** `...` instead, i.e.

```
for number in b...e {
    print(a[number])
}
```

And since you've already tried

```
for number in a[b...e] {
    print(number)
}
```

There is nothing wrong with the above syntax as well. You can use it either way.

Answer (score 0):

An array has a subscript that accepts a Range: `array[range]` and returns a sub-array.

A range of integers can be defined as either b...e or b..<e (There are other ways as well), but not b..<=e

A range itself is a sequence (something that supports a for-in loop)

So you can either do

```
for index in b...e {
    print(a[index])
}
```

or

```
for number in a[b...e] {
    print(number)
}
```

In both cases, it is on you to ensure that b...e are valid indices into the array.